# How to output custom polygon coordinates in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, polygon, output

I am trying to make either a nested manipulate or just a manipulate with two windows: I need one window which functions as:

```
Manipulate[Graphics[Polygon[pt], 
  PlotRange -> 2], {{pt, {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}, {1, -1}}}, 
  Locator, LocatorAutoCreate -> True}]
```

but outputs its coordinates to another window which uses these coordinates to plot a specified graph. I am not sure if Manipulate is even the best option for this, but essentially I am trying to make a visual interface where a user can specify a polygon and then the program uses the information of those coordinates to plot a specified 3D plot.

I think I could figure out how to do this if I knew how to output the coordinates from the manipulate or how to make something that does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Example:

```
GraphicsRow[{
 Manipulate[
   Graphics[Polygon[rs = pt], PlotRange -> 2], 
   {{pt, {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}, {1, -1}}},
     Locator, LocatorAutoCreate -> True}],
  Dynamic@
   ParametricPlot3D[Through[(Interpolation /@ 
        First@(Transpose /@ {Append[#, 0] & /@ rs}))[t]], {t, 1, Length@rs}, 
        PlotRange -> 2]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]